# Is an Interface a Pointer?

Tags: go

Suppose I have the following type definitions:

```
type ICat interface {
  Meow() string
} 

type Cat struct {   
  Name string
}

func (c Cat) Meow() string { 
  return "Meow" 
}
```

When I perform this operation:

```
var a Cat
a.Name = "Tom"
```

A struct of type Cat is allocated in memory and one of its fields gets assigned.

But, if perform the following operation:

```
var b ICat
```

What is exactly being allocated in memory? is a Golang Interface just an struct that holds a pointer to another struct? a "Boxed pointer"?.

Comment: It's (like) a pointer to the concrete data, but only with the methods that the interface makes available.

This is also why you can put anything in an `interface{}` because every type in go implements at least 0 methods.

The actual implementation is explained well by other answers here.

Comment: [Type definition](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L202) and [explanation](https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-internals/blob/master/chapter2_interfaces/README.md#anatomy-of-an-interface)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interface holds two things: a pointer to the underlying data, and the type of that data. So, when you declare

```
var b ICat
```

`b` contains those two elements.

When you do:

```
b:=Cat{}
```

`b` now contains a pointer to a copy of `Cat{}`, and the fact that the data is a `struct Cat`.

When you do:

```
b:=&Cat{}
```

`b` now contains a copy of the pointer to `Cat{}`, and the fact that it is a `*Cat`.